# Is UCMA 4.0 SDK free especially since it has Lync Server 2013 in the installation packages?

Tags: c#, lync, lync-2013, ucma, lync-client-sdk

I have a very basic question and I could not find a direct answer anywhere in google. Is UCMA 4.0 SDK free? I have downloaded it and it has Microsoft Lync Server 2013 in its installation packages, which worried me since Lync is not a free product of Microsoft.

Also, for creating lync bots I need "BuildABot" library. Is it available in UCMA 4.0 SDK?

I know the questions sound pretty silly, but I got nothing direct on google. You can try it out if you don't believe me. Also, I have downloaded UCMA 4.0 SDK but have not installed it because I am working in a client owned environment where any hidden charges will directly impact our customer relationship. If it was not the case I would have gotten my hands dirty by installing it straightaway and seeing the things for myself.

Any informed help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lync / Skype for Business software is actually free.  You can download and install is anywhere.

They make there money on the CAL's ([Client Access Licenses](https://products.office.com/en/skype-for-business/it-pros)).

The standard CAL is free, the other CAL's build on the standard to allow conferencing and PSTN access.

So to answer your question, all SfB SDK's (including UCMA) is free.

Comment: Thanks Shane. Appreciate your help.